# C# - Pass data back to view from ActionFilter via ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a little execution timer and as an extra id like to be able to have the option to display all timing results on the bottom of a view via the ViewData for live timers whilst developing (Opposed to placing all entries in a database to monitor performance) Basically the timer places all time splits into a list> and I am currently trying to pass this into ViewData but when its received the other end I seem unable to cast it back.

```
var Test = _timer.SplitList.Select(e => new { Id = e.Key, Value = e.Value }).OrderBy(e => e.Id).ToList().AsQueryable();
filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Timing"] = Test;
```

Once received by the view it seems to be received as `List<AnonymoyusType<string, double>>`.

How do I go about casting it back to something usable?
Casting back to `List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>` does not seem to work at all!

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous types cannot easily be passed across methods.

You should create a list of Tuples/KeyValuePairs or write your own class.

Also, don't call `AsQueryable()`.

Comment: Its not an anonymous type to begin with, before its loaded into the ViewData it was List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Henry: Then _why_ are you making it into an anonymous type?

Comment: Unless the way I am placing it into the view data is causing it to be cast as anonymous it is doing it its self. As far as I am concerned I am placing the List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> into view data but upon trying to pull the data back out of ViewData it comes out as List<Anonymoustype<string, double>> Am I placing it into viewdata incorrectly? I hope I am making sense, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Henry: What do you think your `Select` call means?

Comment: Yep, got you. Im new to linq/mvc so I made the assumption viewdata couldn't take objects directly. Thanks for your help!